# Question on solution of $\int_{C} \frac{(y,-x)}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \cdot d \vec{C}$ (solution added)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, line-integrals

I am given the integral: $$\int_{C} \frac{(y,-x)}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \cdot d \vec{C}$$
while$$C=\left\{(x, y) \mid x^{10}+y^{10}=100, x \leq 0\right\}$$ while $C$ is oriented downard.

The **solution**  I have seen is :

We can check that $\vec{F}=\frac{(y,-x)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ is a conservative field, thus we can write $$\int_{C} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}+\int_{C_{1}} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}_{1}+\int_{C_{2}} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}_{2}+\int_{C_{3}} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}_{3}=0$$ while $C_{1}=\{x=0, y \in[-\sqrt[10]{100},-r]\}$ , $C_{2}=\{x=0, y \in[r, \sqrt[10]{100}]\}$ , $C_{3}=\left\{x^{2}+y^{2}=r^{2}, x \leq 0\right\}$

Because $\vec{F} \mid _{x=0}=\frac{(y, 0)}{y^{2}}$ we can conclude $\int_{C_{1}} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}_{1}=0=\int_{C_{2}} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}_{2}$

the rest of the solution is just calculation wich is not my goal right now.

**My questions** :

1. how conservative force imply that $\int_{C} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}+\int_{C_{1}} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}_{1}+\int_{C_{2}} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}_{2}+\int_{C_{3}} \vec{F} \cdot d \vec{C}_{3}=0$ where do I see the orientation of the domains he created?
2. I draw the domain $C$ in desmos and I have no idea where the $C_3$ domain came from I just not understand how $C=C_1 +C_2 +C_3$
3. where the $r$ came from in the domain of $C_1$ and $C_2$? what kind of substitute he did?

Comment: The closed loop line integral of a conservative vector field is zero, this is a fact we can look up in any book. From there, if we have an open path, we can draw a series of extra paths on our own (so you can draw your own different from the answer writer's if you wish) that close the loop and say that sum is zero. You can assume the orientation is such that everything is in the same direction. Overall orientation does not matter because it will be zero anyway, so pick an orientation consistent with the original integral.

Comment: Also, $C \neq C_1 + C_2 + C_3$. Rather, $C + C_1 + C_2 + C_3$ is a closed loop.